# Many-to-many on the same table in Phoenix

Tags: many-to-many, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, absinthe

Using Ecto v2.2.6, Phoenix 1.3

I have a table of people (who happen to be related to each other), and another table of relations for those people.  The relations table lists the id of the parent in one column, and the id of the child in another.

```
mix phx.gen.json Accounts Person persons name:string age:integer
mix phx.gen.json Accounts Relationship relationships parent_id:references:persons child_id:references:persons
```

Now, I am about to add belongs_to relationships in the relationships schema (which currently looks like this)

```
  schema "relationships" do
    field :parent_id, :id
    field :child_id, :id
    timestamps()
  end
```

But without the ability to set the id explicitly, it would looks like this (which doesn't seem to work)

```
  schema "relationships" do
    belongs_to :person UserRelations.Accounts.Person 
    belongs_to :person UserRelations.Accounts.Person 
    timestamps()
  end
```

How can I write the relationships schema so that I capture these `belongs_to` relationships?

### Edit

I have set the schema up like this, as per suggestion:

```
  schema "relationships" do
    belongs_to :parent UserRelations.Accounts.Person 
    belongs_to :child UserRelations.Accounts.Person 
    timestamps()
  end
```

I have tried to do something similar with the Person schema as well:

```
  schema "persons" do
    field :age, :integer
    field :name, :string
    many_to_many :parent_of, UserRelations.Accounts.Person, join_through: "relationships"
    many_to_many :child_of, UserRelations.Accounts.Person, join_through: "relationships"
    timestamps()
  end
```

However, when I try to access these relationships (I am doing this through an absinthe/graphql schema), I see that it is looking for a person_id somewhere:

```
[error] Task #PID<0.400.0> started from #PID<0.395.0> terminating
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42703 (undefined_column): column f2.person_id does not exist
```

Comment: Just rename the second one to `belongs_to :child`?

Comment: @Dogbert Attempted to implement that.  Please see edit above.

Comment: I think you need to add `join_keys: [parent_id: :id, child_id: id]` to the first `many_to_many` and the reverse (`[child_id: :id, parent_id: :id]`) to the second one.

Comment: @Dogbert Perfect, It worked exactly as stated.  If you turn those two comments into an answer, I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The name of the two belongs_to relationships need to be different. For example:

   ```
   belongs_to :child, UserRelations.Accounts.Person 
   belongs_to :parent, UserRelations.Accounts.Person
   ```

   With these names, Ecto will infer the foreign key correctly: `child_id` and `parent_id`.
2. For the `many_to_many`, you need to provide `join_keys` to both as Ecto can't infer it from the name of the relationship and the schema module.

   For the first one, you need to add:

   ```
   , join_keys: [parent_id: :id, child_id: :id]
   ```

   And for the second one:

   ```
   , join_keys: [child_id: :id, parent_id: :id]
   ```